# How to select HTML attribute values with powershell

Tags: powershell

I can't figure out how to pull the values from certain attributes of a Invoke-Webrequest

What I have so far:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://someInternalSite.com"
```

From what I get back I get a specific table from the page by ID with the below:

```
 $h = $r.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('table') | Where {$_.id -eq 'SpecificIdOfTable'}
```

Then I can see the table's html by using:

```
$h = $s.getAttribute('outerhtml')
```

The output looks like:

```
<TABLE id=SpecificIdOfTable>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT id=SpecificIdOfTable_0 type=checkbox value=11 name=SpecificIdOfTable$0><LABEL for=SpecificIdOfTable_0>First</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD><INPUT id=SpecificIdOfTable_2 type=checkbox value=12 name=SpecificIdOfTable$2><LABEL for=SpecificIdOfTable_2>Second</LABEL>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT id=SpecificIdOfTable_1 type=checkbox value=13 name=SpecificIdOfTable$1><LABEL for=SpecificIdOfTable_1>Third</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

What I'd like is to get just the attibute values 11, 12, and 13 from each td's value= attribute. I've tried to getByAttribute But I keep getting errors. What I found is that outerHTML is just a string. Since powershell is an object scripting language is there any way to access these attributes as objects and just pull each values without regex? If I need regex what would it look like?

Also a bonus question if someone could answer. I've tried to shorten the request with pipes (to avoid the $h = statement) but have been met with errors. What am I doing wrong when I try to shorten the script with?:

```
$r.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('table') | Where {$_.id -eq 'SpecificIdOfTable'} | select outerHTML
```

or

```
$r.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('table') | Where {$_.id -eq 'SpecificIdOfTable'} | $_.getAttribute('outerhtml')
```

Neither work and I don't know why or how to shorten the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$r.ParsedHTML.GetElementByID('SpecificIdOfTable').GetElementsByTagName('input') |
    Select-Object -Property id, value
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I see I should have been searching for input tag name. Makes more sense that way. How did you know to use Select-Object and not $_ with the pipe command? I can't seem to understand what to start the ladder part of a pipe with.

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the data really.  I only chose `Select-Object` to display the data.  Can you give me an example of what you want to do with the data now that you have it?

Comment: For example your portion | Select-Object  -Property value in my mind is the same as | $_.value since the dot operator is how you access properties and the pipe should send each input as an object with a value as property. In my case i get an error 'Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline'

Comment: Yeah, piping will only work with functions that will except it.  You can either do `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty value` or `| ForEach-Object {$_.value}`.  Though you should use the `Select-Object` option unless you want to run more commands against it.